# General Java unit test question. I have to mock a method (with a List parameter) inside the method I'm testing, Issue is with syntax

Tags: java, mocking

Way too much code to post here so let me try to be more specific.

I'm charged with writing unit tests on a lot of older code.  I ran into a method that needs testing, but it calls a second method in another class, which calls other method in its Class.

ClassA.method is to be tested. It sets 3 attributes,2 strings and a List. then it calls classB.method with those 3 attributes.

so its like this:

```
    ClassA.method(string, string, List)
       get value of local_tag
       get Action from list

       Switch (Action)
           Case Action-1
              Call ClassB.method( str, str, LIST)
              If(local_tag = string set from list )  //  not actuall that straight forward..    
                   set responseString to "xyz"
              break
           Case Action-2
```

```
          etc.
```

My question is, how do you mock a method with a List?

I don't have access to Mockito, but do have EasyMock and PowerMock.  (still not clear on the differences)

Seems like most of the answers I've seen here rely on Mockito.  I've also noticed that most of the answers are 8,9, 10 or more years old, so I wonder it they are still accurate.

I've tried all sorts of syntax to make this work, searched every where, here included. but nothing that seems to address this scenario. (mocking a different class method WITH a List attribute inside the method being tested.

I just want to know if i'm wasting my timne.

Sorry to be so general.  I know you guys like specifics.  I'll add that I'm new to Java and Mocking.  This is how I'm getting "broken in".  I'm just wondering if this is like the Old logger prank where then tell the new guy to go get the chain stretcher.

```
    ClassB myClassB =PowerMock.createMock(ClassB.class);
    expect(classB.method( strA, strB, List)).andReturn();
    verifyAll();
    replayAll();

    or

    ClassB myClassB = PowerMock.createMock(ClassB.class);
    expect(classB.method(EasyMock.isA(classxyz.class)EasyMock.isA(classabc.class),
            EasyMock.isA(List.class))).andReturn();
    replayAll();

    or

    ClassB myClassB =PowerMock.createMock(ClassB.class);
    expect(classB.method(EasyMock.<classA>anyObject(),EasyMock.<List<classB>>anyObject(),
         EasyMock.<classC>.anyObject())).andReturn();
    replayAll();
```

I get all sorts of errors depending on what I try of course. One i get quite frequently is
Required type Void, provided void.
I have no idea what that means, I interpret it to mean, you got the wrong syntax.

Comment: We do like specifics, because without specifics it is impossible to answer questions! If you have a problem with syntax, you need to show the actual code and the actual error. Otherwise it isn't possible to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am trying to set up the code so I can post it.  Its taking a while